# Script to make cells in a column of a spreadsheet bold based on value. (Conditional formatting?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

I need a script that formats the cells in column A bold, but only the cells that contain the word 'Hello'. Also, a similar script that makes the cells containing 'hello' aligned center and one that also formats underlined. You can't conditionally format bold or align or underline in Google Sheets, so I will need a script.

I think it's something like this but I don't know what the last line would be.

```
function formatBold() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
    if (values[row][0] == 'Hello')

};
```

Does anyone know how to complete this script or if there is a better script for the job?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is pretty well documented [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range?hl=en-US#setFontWeight), you can simply use

```
// row+1 because array are 0 indexed while range is 1 indexed
s.getRange(row+1,1).setFontWeight("bold");
```

The other "styles" are available in the same documentation and apply the same way.

EDIT : following your comment, if you want to reset all cells of a specified range to 'normal font' just set to 'normal' in a loop for example.
Please have a look at [this example sheet (make a copy)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dF9ENVFhU3FzQkFWV3FfYU9CTGZCUmc)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry to ask such simple questions but do I just insert your line of code at the bottom of mine to make it work? How can I make the script first make all cells in the sheet font weight normal before applying bold to the specific cells? Many thanks

Comment: yes, just like that :     if (values[row][0] == 'Hello'){s.getRange(row+1,1).setFontWeight("bold")}